# Trait 'Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait' not found error after installing Laracast Generator in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this error after installing **Laracast** Generator plugin in **Laravel 5.4.**

> Trait 'Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait' not found error

Now everytime when I try to run my project with `php` artisan serve this **error** starts coming.

I come to know from many posts that `Laracast Generator` plugin still does not support `Laravel 5.4.` If this is the case then how to completely remove this package from my project so that it will start working again.

Please see screenshot below for the error :-
[**Laracast Generator package issue**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM5zL.png)

Please any one help me to solve the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some people have suggested to change the `composer.json` to :

```
"require": {
        "laracasts/generators": "dev-master as 1.1.4"
},
```

check the [issue](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended/issues/117) on github

Comment: After that you have to run this command
composer update --dev

Comment: @Uahmed yes that's right whenever u make any change in the `composer.json` file u will need to run ` composer update`.

Answer (score 1):

I simply fixed it replacing

```
use Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait;
```

by:

```
use Illuminate\Console\DetectsApplicationNamespace;
```

Good luck!